# Trigger genera error de BulkInsert T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, trigger

Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE SIKOR.dbo.Ordenes (
    orden varchar(200) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    lote varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    fechaInicio date NULL,
    fechaExpo date NULL,
    cantidad int NULL,
    numParte varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    polizaSalida varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    descripcion varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    estatus varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    ordenCompra varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    cliente varchar(MAX) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    fechaEntrega date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Ordenes PRIMARY KEY (orden)
);
```

Para ingresar los datos estoy usando C#-MVC usando EF:

```
public void guardarOrdenTrabajo(string oT, string oC, string lot, string cl, string fI, string fE, string fEx, string can, string part, string pol, string desc, string S)
    {
        DateTime? dateTime = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fI) ? null : new DateTime?(DateTime.Parse(fI)));
        DateTime? dateTime2 = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fE) ? null : new DateTime?(DateTime.Parse(fE)));
        DateTime? dateTime3 = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fEx) ? null : new DateTime?(DateTime.Parse(fEx)));
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(can);
        Ordene ordene = new Ordene
        {
            orden = oT,
            ordenCompra = oC,
            lote = lot,
            cliente = cl,
            fechaInicio = dateTime,
            fechaEntrega = dateTime2,
            fechaExpo = dateTime3,
            cantidad = value,
            numParte = part,
            polizaSalida = pol,
            descripcion = desc,
            estatus = S
        };
        ModelContext modelContext = new ModelContext();
        try
        {
            ((DbContext)modelContext).Entry<Ordene>(ordene).State = (EntityState)4;
            ((DbContext)modelContext).SaveChanges();
        }
        finally
        {
            ((IDisposable)modelContext)?.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Quiero enviar una notificacion por correo cada ves que se ingresa una "Orden" Nueva, y lo quiero hacer por SQL, ya que no es posible por codigo (el fuente se perdio), lo estoy realizando usando un trigger que cree:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_OrdenNueva
ON SIKOR.dbo.Ordenes 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

--BUSCA USUARIOS ENVIAR CORREO
    DECLARE @EmailRecipients VARCHAR(MAX);


    SELECT  @EmailRecipients = COALESCE(@EmailRecipients + ';', '') + Correo
    FROM    SAG.reportes.SegUsuarios u
    INNER JOIN SAG.reportes.TipoUsuarios  c ON c.IdUsuario = u.seg_id  
    WHERE c.IdTipo IN (1, 2, 4, 6)

--BUSCA CORREO DE ID CLIENTE
    DECLARE @Orden VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Orden=(SELECT orden FROM inserted)        
    DECLARE @Cuerpo VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Cuerpo=(SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'E:\Correos\notificacionStandard.html', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents)
    SET @Cuerpo= REPLACE(@Cuerpo, '#Orden#', @Orden)
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Envio Orden',
    @recipients=@EmailRecipients,
    @subject='Orden Ingresada',
    @body= @Cuerpo,
    @body_format='HTML'
  
END;
```

En el `trigger`, leo los correos que se deben enviar, despues abro un archivo y lo adjunto al "`Body`" y envio el correo pero cuando trato de ingresar un nuevo registro desde la aplicacion web me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Observaciones**

1. No estoy haciendo ningun `BulkInsert`, cual seria el problema?
2. Estoy utilizando el usuario "sa" pero este no me deja asignar el
   permiso "BulkAdmin"
3. Si hago el `INSERT` manual desde SQL, no me da ningun error y despues se ejecuta el `trigger` como deberia ser, que tiene raro el `webconfig` de la aplicacion?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema parece ser que es porque se cambia de usuario en algún nivel. No se le pueden asignar permisos al usuario sa porque es el administrador del sistema y tiene acceso a absolutamente todo.

Comment: No entiendo por qué dices que *No estoy haciendo un bulk insert* si claramente `SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'` es una importación de datos por lotes (bulk data import). Echa una mirada a la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) para ver cómo se hace la suplantación de identidad (Impersonation), que creo es el error que estás viendo.

Comment: @Arriel por ahi iba, en vez de leer de un archivo, mejor cree una tabla donde leo el dato, muchas gracias